# Getting last 3 months using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help in getting the last 3 months in javascript. I have generated an excel sheet in which the user has to populate month number in month column and year in year column.

I need to validate that the user has entered correct month and year combination based on current year.

User fill up the excel and upload it to node js fastify server. After that, I need to validate the month and year.

example:

1. If the current year is 2018 and the month is Jan(1). Users can enter 2017 in a year and 10 in a month.
2. The current year is 2019 and the month is 10. User can enter 8 in month

Please guide me. How can I achieve this?

```
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
  'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

const getLastThreeMonths = () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const previousMonths = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    previousMonths.push(`${months[(now.getMonth() - i)]}`);
  }
  return previousMonths;
};

console.log(getLastThreeMonths());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer:

```
const dateValidator = (month, year) => {
  const allowedRange = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i += 1) {
    const current = new Date();
    current.setMonth(current.getMonth() - i + 1);
    allowedRange.push({ month: current.getMonth() + 1, year: current.getFullYear() });
  }
  return allowedRange.find(ar => ar.month === month && ar.year === year);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

one working code sample is here ..You can change the content as per your requirement.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {      
        var date = new Date();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        if (month == "1") {
            year = date.getFullYear() - 1;
        }
        month = month - 2;
        $("#month").on('change', function () {
            if ($("#month").val() != month) { alert("not valid month"); }

        });

         $("#year").on('change', function () {
            if ($("#year").val() != year) {alert("not valid year"); }

        });
    });



 <input type="text" id="month" placeholder="put month here"/>
<input type="text" id="year"  placeholder="put year here"/>
```